# Representing compatibility between two users in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm currently building a site that compares users based on common interests but I'm unsure what is the best way to represent the relationships between each user.

I've attempted it by creating a user table, with a user_id field and a compatibility table that stores a calculated compatibility score for each combination of users.

```
COMPATIBILITY TABLE
---------------------------------------------
user_one             | FOREIGN_KEY(user_id)
user_two             | FOREIGN_KEY(user_id)
compatibility_score  | 0.5
```

(Note that for any two users the compatibility score will always be the same, so user_one and user_two are effectively interchangable)

Then if I wanted to get a list of say the top 10 most compatible users for a user with the id '11' I could run:

```
SELECT * FROM `compatibility` WHERE `user_two_id` = 11 OR `user_one_id` = 11 ORDER BY `score` ASC LIMIT 10
```

But I'd then have to do some extra work with the results to determine whether user_one or user_two is the user to output. (Ie, not the current user #11)

It also concerns me that with each new user the table size will increase exponentially, but perhaps this is unavoidable.

Is this the most effective and efficient way to store this kind of relationship? Should I be tweaking my design or be going for a different approach completely? I'm so new to this I'm not even sure what kind of things I should be googling to figure this out so if anybody could point me in the right direction, it would be a huge help.

Comment: if the user fields are interchangeable, then a simple `where 11 in (user_one_id, user_two_id)` would handle the filtering. figuring out which of the two is the "other" user would be pretty simple as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an acceptable way of doing this!

1. You're using a junction table to model a many-to-many relationship (good).
2. You're using foreign keys (and hopefully a composite key) to ensure uniqueness between `user_one` and `user_two` (good).
3. Defining an index on `<user_one, user_two, compatibility_score>` should allow fairly fast retrievals using an index-only plan (good).

I do think that there's a slightly better way to do it but I can't think of what it might be.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I'm going to press ahead with this method and focus on optimising the queries I'm making as much as possible